# Populate JSON content in table using angular6

Tags: html, angular, typescript, html-table, angular6

I have JSON to construct table by populating its header and body dynamically. Could anyone suggest the problem is in JSON or table iteration.

JSON:

```
this.columns = ["role1", "role2"];
this.permission = [
    {
      "role1": [{ "name": "master" }],
      "master": [ { "name": "sub1", "read" : true, "Write" : true }, 
        { "name": "sub2",  "read" : true, "Write" : true  } ]
    },
    {
      "role2": [{ "name": "master" }, { "name": "support" }],
      "master": [{ "name": "sub1", "read" : true, "Write" : false  }, 
                  { "name": "sub2",  "read" : true, "Write" : false  }],
      "support": [{ "name": "sub3",  "read" : true,  "Write" : true  
                  }]
    }
  ]
```

HTML:

```
<table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2"> Modules </th>
        <th colspan="2" *ngFor="let col of columns">
          {{col}}
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let char of permission; let first=first">
          <td> read</td>
          <td> write</td>
        </ng-container>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let char of permission">
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
          {{char[col]}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of errors in your json. You can use [JSON lint](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate (although JSON will require you to put keys into double quotes whereas typescript doesnt)

Try again with this for `permissions`:

```
this.permission =
  [ {
      role1: [{
        master: { sub1: { read: true, write: true },
                  sub2: { read: true, write: true } },
        support: { sub3: { read: true, write: false } },
        admin: { sub4: { read: false, write: false } }
      }],
      role2: [{
        master: { sub1: { read: true, write: false },
                  sub2: { read: true, write: false } },
        support: { sub3: { read: true, write: true } },
        admin: { sub4: { read: false, write: false } }
      }],
      role3: [{
        master: { sub1: { read: true, write: true },
                  sub2: { read: true, write: true } },
        admin: { sub4: { read: true, write: true } }
      }]
    },
    {
      role1: [{ 
        master: {
          sub1: { read: true, write: true },
          sub2: { read: true, write: true }
        },
        support: {
          sub3: { read: true, write: false }
        },
        admin: {
          sub4: { read: false, write: false }
        }
      }],
      role2: [{
        master: {
          sub1: { read: true, write: false },
          sub2: { read: true, write: false }
        },
        support: {
          sub3: { read: true, write: true }
        },
        admin: {
          sub4: { read: false, write: false }
        }
      }],
      role3: [{
        master: {
          sub1: { read: true, write: true },
          sub2: { read: true, write: true }
        },
        admin: {
          sub4: { read: true, write: true }
        }
      }]
    }
  ];
```

Comment: Thanks for  JSON lint , let me try with this.

Comment: @NithyaNeela are the values such as `role1`, `master`, `sub1` variable or can they be variable? If values are static you can simplify this a lot

Comment: No, it is not static. I think now i structured json.

Comment: i updated the json as key value pair. Can you suggest is it valid to bring the expected table result

Comment: You have a pretty complex table with lots of nested objects and values. I am trying to reproduce it but it is a lot of markup

Comment: Ok Thanks, i am also trying

Comment: To translate `[Object object]` use `{{char[col] | json}}`

Answer (score 0):

If it returns a object you can do that

```
{{char[col] | json}}
```

to see what is in the object.